# highlighting background of image in horizontal ListView in android application

Tags: android

in my project when I select one image from the horizontal listview it is highlighting,but when I select another image,1st selected image highlighting too..I want at a time only one image should be highlighted. please help me out.

Here is my selector code,

```
<item android:state_selected="true"android:drawable="@drawable/light_
blue"/> 
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /></selector>
```

xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parentchillayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:padding="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Iv_front"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bag"
    /></LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos,long arg3)
        { arg1.setSelected(true);
          Iv_Product.setImageResource(data.get(pos));
            position = pos;
        }
```

Comment: you can do in adapter class.using logic

Comment: @Charmi check below answer

Answer (score 0):

The condition is mentioned in your selector code itself.

```
<item android:state_selected="false" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

First update youe `selector code`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Remove your this code no need to do this.

```
public static int mSelectedItem =-1; // declare it as global vaiable
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos,long arg3)
        { 
            mSelectedItem = position;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Keep track in your getView of position and setbackground

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            // set your color
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but this is not exactly what I want,I want the selected item to be in selected state(in green color)until I select another item.

Comment: @Charmi then uncommet this code `arg1.setSelected(true);
            //Iv_Product.setImageResource(data.get(pos));
            //position = pos;`

Comment: check the updated answer and make changes and if it helps please use tick mark so we help each other.

Comment: i have made changes in my code as u said but Its still not giving what i want ..i want the selected item to be in selected state until i click on another item

Comment: @Charmi best of luck i try my best.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and here I am sharing it so that it can be useful to someone.

```
for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
      if(i == position)
{ parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
}
else { parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
} }
```